# How to say "I wouldn't go so far as to say..." in Mandarin

Tags: translation, grammar

I'm searching for a common way to say "I wouldn't go so far as to say that" in Mandarin. The only translation of this expression, that I found in a dictionary, is :

```
It's good, but I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's great.
挺好的，但是我不會極端到說棒極了。
```

However, since I have not found any other translation of "極端到" that expresses the idea of "go so far as to", I wonder if is this is a common way to say it.

Comment: I would say: 可以，但远称不上极好。

Comment: The corresponding expression in Chinese really varies, all three answers are correct as of now.

Comment: see dictionaries, submit "go so far as to" e.g. to iciba, ichacha: iciba:她不至于不来上学.他不至于不来开会 吧 ?有些热衷于自己动手的人甚至自己组装电脑.(En at iciba)
ichacha: go so far as to disregard the facts    竟然不顾事实...

Answer (score 13):

It is more natural to say

> 还没有……到……地步

For example, 挺好的，但还没有**好**到**那个**地步。

Or

> it tastes fine, but I would not go so far as to say that it is delicious

can be

> 味道还行，但还没有好吃到十分美味的地步

Well, if you were in a more oral conversation, you would normally say

> 但也没有很/特别……
>
> 但也不是很/特别……

For example

> I went to the national park, which was a good trip, but I would not go so far as to say that it is wonderful

could be

> 我去了国家公园，感觉还行，但也不是特别好玩

Answer (score 5):

It's good, but I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's great.

This sentence should be translated to 
挺不錯的，但還不到非常好。

I never heard 極端到說棒極了, It's very odd, and no one would say that way.

Answer (score 4):

至于 can be used to interpret it.

> It's good, but I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's great. 挺好的，但(我)还不至于说它非常好。

Answer (score 1):

As in oral expressions i might say

> 还好吧，但是也没**那么**好

where I would put stress on the bold part. This might not be the exact translation of the sentence you want to say [maybe we could translate it back to "It is good, but not that good", although this sentence might be seldomly used by natives], but it is a commonly used informal expression to say something like that in your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"过誉" is what you are looking for.

It's good, but I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's great.
它还不错，但我不会**过誉**其为伟大。